# Deleting the Docker disk image size

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm using docker and I got an error "No space on the drive" when I tried to use the docker. So, I searched online and found that I had to remove the the unused images from the docker. So, I used the command

```
docker system prune --all
```

It deleted about `~30`GB of the images. But When I run the docker again I got the same "No space" issue and when I checked the disk image size it showed me that `64 GB used` even though I deleted the unused containers.

I had to increase the size of the drive every time when I use docker.

```
docker images output

REPOSITOY          TAG             IMAGE ID         CREATED        SIZE
postgres           latest         aal783da97       2 days ago      6.32GB
redis              latest         aal783da98       2 days ago      6.32GB
mysql              latest         aal783da99       2 days ago      6.32GB
airflow_worker     latest         aal783da91       2 days ago      6.32GB
airflow_scheduler  latest         aal783da92       2 days ago      6.32GB
```

[image]

How do I delete all the `64.1 GB`?

Comment: Did you have 94.1 Gb before the system-prune? Prune removes unused data. Maybe there is 64Gb used data on the Docker environment? Check "docker images".   To remove all those half-baked images names "<none>" use the following command:  docker images | grep -e "<none>" | awk '{print "docker rmi " $3}' | bash

Comment: @BertC I had to increase the size by 94.1 GB. I have checked but there are no unused images. Every time I do docker compose up, it is taking space on my disk. Don't know how to delete this data

Comment: Can you do a "docker images" command and post the output in your question? (Obfuscating the image-names if you want)  And if you do a docker-compose which fails to run, it leaves an half-baked image. You can see them in "docker images", they are named "<none>".

Comment: @BertC I added it to my question

Comment: It is odd that the size of all those images are the same. What OS are you running on your host?

Comment: In accordance to the previous remark: Another odd thing is that those images are not as large as shown here. Postgres is 315 Mb on both my macbook and Ubuntu.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I'm running on mac os

Comment: Hi. Have you managed it? I have the same with docker desktop but in windows